# How to control where an ad banner appears on screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, banner

Good morning,

I am trying to set an ad banner to appear somewhere NOT top nor bottom on the screen, so what I have been doing is this;

```
 if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {

        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        CGFloat screenXPos = (screenWidth /2);
        CGFloat screenYPos = screenHeight - 150;
        [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(screenXPos, screenYPos)];
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    }else{

        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        CGFloat screenXPos = (screenWidth /2);
        CGFloat screenYPos = screenHeight -480;
        [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(screenXPos, screenYPos)];
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
```

It is quite untidy, and does not really work how I want, for example, I would want the ad banner to appear around 150 pixels off the top for ANY device (iPad/iPhone etc)

Would I be better creating a banner view in Interface builder? But if that is the case, how would I implement the above code into that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
       bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,150);
     [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(screenXPos, screenYPos)];
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
```

Comment: Hi, there is an error in that code regarding screenXPos not being declared - also not really what I was after, as it's essentially exactly the same as I am already doing...150 is not enough on the iPad, yet is ok on the iPhone, etc etc